# drawing a bar in js that visually displays var number values (-50 to +50)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a project that has 8 variables that can go to -50/+50 each and they are currently displayed as a number, but I am looking to snazz it up a bit with a visual bar that adapts on page load to what the current value of each var is.

As a rough guideline and to demonstrate what I'm looking for, it should be something like this -

[image: example]

I have tried using noUIslider to handle it but it's not working as intended (the user is not supposed to be able to 'slide' the slider and I cannot get it to set the value based off my variables).

So my question is, is there a library/codepen/jsfiddle out there already doing this? And if not, what would be the best way of building such a thing?

Comment: Bump? Still trying to wrap my head around this one